# Ubuntu22.04 cannot connect to the network after the time is messed up

Tags: networking

My computer has dual systems. Windows and Linux read RTC in different formats, but I don’t want to change the reading methods of these two systems. Windows can connect to the network after the time is messed up, but Ubuntu cannot. Is there any solution? Thank you.